# elasticsearch post mapping in search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index, where each record looks like that:

```
{
    "id": "some-id",
    "vendorFilter": { ... },
    "storeFilter": { ... },
    "content": { ... }
}
```

All fields like `vendorFilter` or `storeFilter` are only used for the filter logic on determine, which items to return. But the client only cares about the stuff in the content field. It is possible to tell elasticsearch to just return the content field to reduce traffic? because the filter values are in general very large.

Comment: you can specify which fields to return in source=[""]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering). When you have a query please prepone the source instruction:

```
GET /_search

{
    "_source": "content",
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "storeFilter" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```